# Python >= 3.8 container on GCP (Vertex AI Workbench)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-dl-platform

Problem: Python 3.7 is outdated, yet prebuilt containers for Vertex AI Workbench are all are built w/ 3.7.

Is there a way to modify (e.g. rebuild the base containers that work w/ Vertex AI workbench), e.g. perhaps by setting an ARG command to rebuild a working base container with Python >= 3.8?

Alternatively, does any code exist to demonstrate building an image compatible with Workbench?

Comment: Here's the best alternative I've found, but I haven't tested this yet: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/custom-container#requirements

Answer (score 0):

As @Brian Bien mentioned in the comments, and per my R&D the best alternative as of now is to use a [Custom Container](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/custom-container#requirements).

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

GCP's latest workbench container now arrives with a later version of python.